# xslt 2.0 : using HashMap

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

i have a java method that returns a map to xslt.

XSLT method call -

```
<xsl:variable name="mapValue" select="class:returnMap()">
```

Java Method -

```
public Map<String,List<String>> returnMap(){
    Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("1");
    list.add("2");
    map.put("a",list);
    map.put("b",list);
    return map
}
```

how do I fetch the list value of the map in XSLT 2.0?
i tried assigning the values to a variable using the below format,

```
<xsl:variable name="valueOfA" select="$mapValue/entry[@key='a']"/>
<xsl:variable name="valueOfB" select="$mapValue/entry[@key='b']"/>
```

but, i got the below exception.

```
XPTY0019: Required item type of first operand of '/' is node(); supplied value has item type java:java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

if i try to display the value of $mapValue it prints fine.

Comment: Which XSLT 2.0 processor do you use, which version, which edition? Have you checked its documentation like e.g. https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.7/extensibility/ or http://manual.altova.com/RaptorXML/raptorxmlserver/index.html?fxmisc_java.htm

Comment: Also note if you use Saxon then with 9.8 (all editions) you could use XSLT 3 with XPath 3.1 maps where you could simply convert your Java `Map` into an XPath 3.1 `map` using https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XdmMap.html#makeMap-java.util.Map- on the Java side of the code and return that to XSLT/XPath where you can then use the functions like `map:keys` from https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-map-keys. For Saxon HE you would need to implement and register your function as an integrated extension function.

Answer (score 0):

The error message shows that you are using Saxon. The rules for conversion between Java objects and XPath values depend on which processor you use, so this is relevant.

If you are using Saxon then you have access to XSLT 3.0, and to the new map/array data types, which means that you can achieve what you are trying to achieve without calling out to Java.

The specific error you are getting is because (as the message says) $mapValue is not a node, so you can't access its children using the "/" operator. If you use an XSLT 3.0 map instead then you can access an entry using, for example `$mapValue?a`.